# After set array into foreach cant count that?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i should find today timestamp and if count more than 3 return false if not return true

query :

```
while( $record = $result->fetchAssoc() ) { 
    $items[] = $record;
}
```

output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 1570877769
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 1570877783
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 1510877794
        )

)
```

Foreach :

```
    foreach ($items as $Newarrays) {

    }
```

after use a foreach loop look :

```
Array
(
    [timestamp] => 1570877769
)
Array
(
    [timestamp] => 1570877783
)
Array
(
    [timestamp] => 1570877794
)
```

this step i want count `timestamp`s to find 3 timestamp today but `count` return `1` and not work !

**UPDATE FULL CODE:**

```
$query->condition('node_revision.nid', $node->nid);
```

how do that?
thanks for you helps...

Comment: Where did you use count function can you show it which is displaying 1 in return?

Comment: if ($accessdate === $currentdate) {
   if (count($timestamp) >3) { }
 }

Comment: Yes, Please add your whole code so that we can assume what did you tried and where are making mistake. Edit question and put whole code.

Comment: `count( $items) > 3`

Comment: i should find today timestamp `$items` have all timestamp !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this. in this output I'm getting a `count` as `2`

```
   $items = array(array('timestamp'=>1570877769),array('timestamp'=>1570877783),array('timestamp'=>1510877794));


    $currentdate=date("d-m-Y");

    $count = 0;
    foreach ($items as $newarrays) {
        if($currentdate == date("d-m-Y",$newarrays['timestamp'])){
            $count++;
        }
    }
    echo $count;
    exit;
```

https://paiza.io/projects/WpyO1P-9Oaj3G_gYq4VeQA

Comment: are you have a replacement for `exit;` evertime use that script stopped !

Comment: Yes, you may remove it. I just want to show you that how to count values from array don't focus on exit; you may remove it.